# angular material custom palette toolbar font color

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, palette

How can I change the text color of the toolbar by defining my own custom palette ? Or in general how can I set the color of the text ?

```
app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('accent', {
    '50': '#FFEB3B',
    '100': '#FFEB3B',
    '200': '#FFEB3B',
    '300': '#FFEB3B',
    '400': '#FFEB3B',
    '500': '#FFEB3B',
    '600': '#FFEB3B',
    '700': '#FFEB3B',
    '800': '#FFEB3B',
    '900': '#FFEB3B',
    'A100': '#FFEB3B',
    'A200': '#FFEB3B',
    'A400': '#FFEB3B',
    'A700': '#FFEB3B',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'dark',    // whether, by default, text (contrast)
                                        // on this palette should be dark or light
    'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100', //hues which contrast should be 'dark' by default
     '200', '300', '400', 'A100'],
    'contrastLightColors': undefined
 });

    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('primary', {
    '50': '#FFEB3B',
    '100': '000000',
    '200': '000000',
    '300': '000000',
    '400': '#FFEB3B',
    '500': '000000',
    '600': '000000',
    '700': '000000',
    '800': '000000',
    '900': '#FFEB3B',
    'A100': '#FFFFFF',
    'A200': '000000',
    'A400': '000000',
    'A700': '#FFEB3B',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',    // whether, by default, text (contrast)
                                        // on this palette should be dark or light
    'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100', //hues which contrast should be 'dark' by default
     '200', '300', '400', 'A100'],
    'contrastLightColors': []

  });


  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('primary')
    .accentPalette('accent');
});
```

The attribute contrastDefaultColor controls the color of the text in the toolbar but only can be set to 'light' or 'dark'so it would be white or black but I want it to be yellow.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you'll have to define your own CSS rules e.g. :

```
md-tabs > ..> md-tab-item {
    color: yellow;
}
```